# Probability of Primitive Root (Mod 43)

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

Probability of Primitive Root (mod 43)
Q: If you independently select 5 random integers from the reduced residue system (mod 43), What is the probability that at least one of your integers is a primitive root (mod 43)?

So I know that if I select a random integer from the reduced residue system (mod 43), the probability that my integer is a primitive root is (# or primitive roots)/ phi(43) or 12/42.

I thought that since the 5 random integers were independently selected the probability would be (12/42)^5, but that not correct. Can someone please help me understand how to do this!

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the question is that you want to choose $5$ different primitive roots, therefore given that interpretation the answer should be:

$$\frac{12}{42} \times \frac{11}{41}\times \frac{10}{40}\times \frac{9}{39} \times\frac{8}{38}$$

I'm assuming that there are $12$ primitive roots in $\mathbb{Z}_{43}$ as you have said. (Sorry that I didn't leave this as a comment, I can't post a comment until I have 50 reputation scores).

**Remark:** I just checked that the number of primitive roots modulo $n$ (if any exists) is given by $\varphi(\varphi(n))$. The reason is that if $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has a primitive root, then it's cyclic and the number of primitive roots therefore are equal to the number of generators of this cyclic group. I thought some people might find this useful. In this case, $\varphi(\varphi(43))$ is $12$.

**EDIT:**

The probability that I initially calculated gives you the probability of all the 5 selected integers being primitive!

You want **at least** one of them to be primitive. That's a different probability. Because there are several different cases that need to be handled, namely choosing 1 primitive and 4 non-primitives, 2 primitive and 3 non-primitives, et cetera.

The probability of choosing **at least** one primitive root is equal to the compliment of the event that you choose none!

In that case, you will have:

$$1-(\frac{30}{42}\times \frac{29}{41}\times \frac{28}{40}\times \frac{27}{39}\times \frac{26}{38})$$

Comment: Thank you for sharing that. I did try and answer and is incorrect. This question is frustrating. Thank you for feedback though!

Comment: @Anonymous: I updated my answer. Please note that the statement "at least one primitive root has been chosen" is the opposite of "no primitive root has been chosen". Therefore, their respective probabilities are compliments of each other.

Comment: That is incorrect. :( I double checked to make sure I typed the question right and I did.

Comment: @Anonymous: What is the final answer? Have you checked if the two numbers are actually equal or not?

Comment: I don't know the final answer. I am using a homework program called webwork so I can type in the answer and it will tell me if it is correct or incorrect. So you're correct in that probability of at least one = 1 - probability of none. So I'm unsure as to why your answer above is incorrect.

Comment: Ahhh So I figured it out!! So because we "INDEPENDENTLY" selected 5 random integers our answer should've been 1-((30/42)^5), since we could've had the same number all five times. Thank you so much for your help. I couldn't have done it without you!

Comment: @Anonymous: Yes. That's also the other interpretation of the problem if you allow choosing one number more than once. I'm glad that it finally worked.